# Standard/common mark up language for user provided content?

Tags: wiki, markup

I suppose this might be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342961/what-markup-language-for-richly-formated-content), but I'm wondering if there's a standard/popular mark up language for wiki and similar style user provided content.  With the proliferation of different mark up syntaxes out there it seems like one would be a defacto one to implement.  There appears to have been at least [one group](http://www.usemod.com/cgi-bin/mb.pl?WikiMarkupStandardWorkingGroup) that wanted to create a standard (and an RFC for it), but they appear to have fizzled out around mid-2005.

So does anybody know what the standard/most popular one is?  If there isn't one, what's the easiest for users but has a good flexibility for advanced users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is popular in some circles. In addition to the original version in Perl, there's a C version called [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/markdown/) and several other implementations including one in [Lua](http://www.frykholm.se/files/markdown.lua).

There's a list of lightweight markup languages [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lightweight_markup_languages).

Comment: My vote's for Markdown. Most wikis and blog engines have plug-ins for it now, turning it into kind of a lingua franca. Which is good, because I get tired of looking up the link, bold, and code syntax for every similar markup language.

Answer (score 0):

No standard that I know of.

I'd say the most popular (well, in the projects I tend to follow at least) seems to tend towards [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and [Textile](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/) these days.

It's often a matter of preference. My preference goes to Markdown but there wouldn't be that much to argue about if someone preferred another markup.